# Multiple Carousell Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
  <div class="col-md-5">
          <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img data-src="holder.js/500x500/auto/#777:#555/text:First slide" alt="First slide">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img data-src="holder.js/500x500/auto/#666:#444/text:Second slide" alt="Second slide">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img data-src="holder.js/500x500/auto/#555:#333/text:Third slide" alt="Third slide">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
        </div>
```

I have multile bootstrap carousels on my site, thing is all of them "work" just the manual control is not. Only these data-target little buttons work one the 1st slider and not on the other 2 galleries. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Did u change id="carousel-example-generic" for all carousels?

Comment: yes i did this is the site http://www.ibci.hr/webapp2/. 
The galleries are in the "marketing part of the site"

Comment: What is manual control? Do you want add left and right arrows?

Comment: by that I mean "carousel-indicators" ( those 3 little buttons on the bottom of the page aka manual control ), No no i don't want arrows, these carousel-indicators work fine for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use same id for multiple carousel. It is wrong html.

Change these ides and related links.

```
<div data-ride="carousel" class="carousel slide" id="carousel-example-generic1"> 
 <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic1" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic1" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  ....
</div>

<div data-ride="carousel" class="carousel slide" id="carousel-example-generic2"> 
 <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic2" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic2" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic2" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  ....
</div>
```